# Phalcon PHP: Set model source dynamically on initialize

Tags: php, crud, entity-attribute-value, phalcon

I've got a few simple EAV tables that all have the same structure, but are for different purposes:

```
item_attribute
id | attribute_name | size_limit

item_attribute_map
id | attr_id | source_id | value
```

And:

```
transaction_attribute
id | attribute_name | size_limit

transaction_attribute_map
id | attr_id | source_id | value
```

The logic that will use these is for all intensive purposes identical, but it will be referencing different tables obviously.

So, I decided I'd simply make a model that could have it's source changed, something like this:

```
class Attribute extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public $id;
    public $attr_id;
    public $source_id;
    public $value;

    public function getSource($param){
        return $param.'_attribute_map';
    }
}
```

I've considered overriding _*construct(), passing a parameter, setting it, calling parent::*_construct() and being done with it; but that doesn't seem remotely elegant. Is there any way to pass a parameter to initialize()? Should I be doing this another way? I'm not in to the idea of doing all this work in the controller, because these two table sets to wildly different things, and I'd like to use this sort of database technique further.

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I wasn't clear and I'll edit.

EDIT: Well I tried my inelegant solution of using __construct() and determined that it's a final method, and now I'm actually out of ideas.

EDIT 2: Well I've found a way to do what I want (sort of), which is by calling setSource() after the model is instantiated. I'm not a big fan of this though because it's linking the model to a table, and then immediately linking it to another table afterwards.

EDIT 3: I've run across the idea of setting up a base class that will accept creation requests for three separate models, but in those cases will actually only create one model, and handle method requests accordingly. This is definitely a better solution than the last, but I don't like having global rules for specific cases, I'd rather have specific rules for specific cases within the scope of those situations. I'll use this method for now, but I'll leave this question open in the hopes that someone has a better idea.

Comment: About your last approach on `EDIT 3`, can't you simply override the rules and behaviors from your base class? _"The logic that will use these is for all intensive purposes are identical"_ could you provide some of this logic on your question. I can hardly tell what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Frankly I left out the logic because I wanted to know if there was a way to dynamically set the source of a model before it's set the first time.

Comment: So, could you please update the question with your latest attempt, like the base class you mentioned?

Comment: did you get the solution for the question. If yes please share the solution

Answer (score 0):

if you want same methods to be available on some models, just create base model and extend it in your models instead of extending \Phalcon\Mvc\Model

```
class BaseModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
  // functions what you need in several other models
}

class Attribute extends BaseModel  {
  // functions what you need in several other models
}

class Attribute extends BaseModel  {
  // functions what you need in several other models
}
```

I don't understand if you tried this option, or not? Maybe you done something similar? You should add more code in your question.